# How can I make particles not pass through the surface and not get "stuck" in it?

Tags: particles, physics

I want to make the falling autumn leaves. 
I did a system of particles, but when the leaf particles reach the surface, (to which I applied collision modifier), they do not entirely remain on the surface, but are "stuck" in it.

How can I make particles not pass through the surface and not get "stuck" in it?

[image]

Comment: I think I can get you an answer by the end of the day. I'm fairly sure it's because particles are point based, so they're only detecting one collision point instead of a full mesh. I think the way to go is either rigid bodies, or soft bodies. Rigid bodies would probably be easier.

Comment: Thanks, @TARDISMaker, but in this case i will have to manually create each leaf?.. And how to make them rotate and move naturally? ..

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Just add rigid body properties to the meshes the particles are duplicating

Comment: Probably with some force fields. Wait, do you need them to start at different times? If so, I might have to think about his a bit harder. I have a method, it's just not very efficient compared to particles. @NoviceInDisguise applying rigid body the original mesh contols the particle collisions?

Comment: @TARDISMaker Thank you! I think in this case,to make particles fall to the surface at different periods of time, I can use multiple emitters with different settings. Nevertheless, I am very interested to know more about your method!
Now, however, two major problems are: 1) Particles "stuck" in the surface. 2) particles continue to rotate after the fall on the surface (I post it in another question on this site, but so far no response).

Comment: @TARDISMaker I think so, I seem to remember doing that. You might want to test it

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I just tried to apply to the original meshes (leaves) rigid body and soft body, the result is the same. But maybe I'm doing something wrong? I really need to fix this as soon as possible, and I would be very glad to see a more detailed description, if possible.

Comment: I don't have a full on method, I just have some ideas that I'm going to mess around with tonight. Both rigid body and soft body at the same time? Basically a rigid body is for meshes that stay rigid, soft bodies are for meshes that bend a bit. You'll probably be fine with rigid bodies. When is your deadline?

Comment: You might want to check this addon out: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?279329-Copy-Particles-to-Rigid-Bodies It might do what you need but it won't be as fast as a particle system and it's probably quite buggy. I haven't had time to try it out. You also might want to check out this thread, it has similar problems to what you have, exept that it's at a much larger scale: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?338993-1-000-Cars-Falling-from-Sky I don't know how much of it will be useful, but it could be helpful.

Comment: @TARDISMaker, No, I tried rigid body and soft body separately. 
There is no formal deadline, but I need to finish it as soon as possible - today or tomorrow.
Thank you very much for the information!

Comment: I've been messing around with this for a few minutes, and I'm not finding anything that would work. Rigid bodies are more for heavy objects and don't work well with light objects. I haven't tried soft bodies, and particles have the same problem. I think the best way to take care of it might be to just cover it up. Some things you could to, are hide the fact that they are sticking into the ground with grass (I think how they are behaving is actually fairly similar to how they would with grass), you could also carefully position the origin to maximize the likelihood of realistic collisions.

Comment: @TARDISMaker, Thank you very much, I made leaves with the help of this addon!: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?279329-Copy-Particles-to-Rigid-Bodies
But, i do not know why, the animation stops at frame 250, while i need to animation lasted longer. Could you take a look, if you have a minute? Here blender file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35724 I need to finish this shot today. Maybe you'll understand why the animation stops at frame 250, and how to fix it? Here's a video to make it clear what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1v2jDqNOv8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: That seemed to work quite well! It's the rigid body cache. This is basically how much the simulation will bake, after that amount, it won't bake anything else. It's found in the scene tab of the properties view. Just set that to 500 and you should be good! You should probably answer your question (so you get the points :) ) and so that the question can be properly closed.

Comment: @TARDISMaker Yes, problem solved! :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23085/discussion-between-maxim-velichkin-and-tardis-maker).